# How to pass parameter to jsonb_path_query from spring jpa data

Tags: json, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, jsonb

I have spring JPA query

```
@Query(value = "select jsonb_path_query(payload,'$.structures.array[*].businessRelationships.array[?1]')\\:\\:text    from fmk_t_contract where jsonb_path_exists(payload,'$.structures.array[*].businessRelationships ? (@.array[?1].brlStId == ?2)')", nativeQuery = true)
```

String findByJsonValueByBrlId(int index, String brStId);

I want to pass index and brStId to above spring jpa native query

Comment: i deleted my answer because it is not actual one and i think appropriate is answer of this question [jsonb-path-query-in-jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42665687/query-a-postgres-jsonb-using-spring-jpa-query-annotation)

Comment: Nope still it didn’t answer my problem, I am using jsonb_path_query inside single I want to pass the parameter.